# "Tower of Hanoi" recursion not as simple as it seems

Tags: recursion

I was asked to implement the "Tower of Hanoi" recursion, and my mind worked this logic:

1. Move 1 disk from start onto buffer
2. Move the rest from start onto goal
3. Move 1 disk from buffer onto goal

Every test passed except for "Towers_of_hanoi(3, start, goal)"

Turns out the correct implementation is:

1. Move n - 1 disks from start onto buffer
2. Move 1 from start onto goal
3. Move the n - 1 disk from buffer onto goal

I have learned to think about recursion as a way solving a problem in terms of simpler ones, and in my mind, both implementations do that. What is the fundamental flaw in my thinking vs the correct way of breaking it down?

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Towers of Hanoi is that you can only have 3 stacks, and you can't put larger disks on top of smaller disks, so you need to make sure that the stack you're using as 'buffer' does not contain any smaller disks before you make the recursive call.  In your case, you move the smallest disk to the buffer and then attempt to recurse to move the rest of the stack, but that will fail as the buffer is not usable.

Comment: Chris, i do see the flaw, but i just find it strange that educators don't think such technicalities should be mentioned. Every video or lecture i have seen involving this problem gives this "brushed over" high level explanation of the algorithm. 
Well if that way of thinking is all that is necessary for the recursion, my algorithm should work just fine. (That was a rant :)

Comment: Your algorithm does work -- as long as its ok to put large disks on top of small disks.  If you work through it, it moves the whole stack to the buffer (an upside-down tower) and then moves it to the goal.

Comment: @user96454 As someone who actually teaches this and uses the Towers of Hanoi example, I always make a point to mention that the reason the algorithm works is that the larger disks can be ignored when moving the smaller disks on top. I'm sorry that whoever taught this didn't make that point clearer!